# db name, username and password in Azure to configure wordpress db

Tags: database, wordpress, azure

I'm using Microsoft Azure to run a wordpress site. I have to convert a static HTML site to a new wordpress site, therefore need to link to my existing db. Where do I find my database's username, password, so that I could correctly log this into wp-config.php file?

Comment: In AZURE portal there is option for Azure SQL.

Comment: I finally found it. Do you know how to unlink the existing database in Azure and connect it to new one?

Comment: Unlink? Do you mean you want to delete database?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the database and now I created a new database. I found a way to unlink old database and link new one, but the website is apparently not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

it depends to the way wiche you have created withe it your database so if you created it in azure mysql server you have to go to graphice interface and then to put your server name in the host and the connection name use it in user
then use same password that you have used it when you created the server